# Windows Level sounds lags/crashes system

Tags: windows, audio, desktop-computer

So I just built my new system. Specs below.

After getting everything set up, I've encountered a weird issue. Any windows level sounds lag my PC out.

I am saying Windows level sound, because I can play youtube and video games with sound and have no issue. Discord, Spotify, or any other application/windows sound causes the issue. The sound will play, but its extremely choppy/laggy, and it progressively gets worst till the computer completely locks up. It wont blue screen or show any other error message, and windows troubleshooting cant find the issue.

It only happens through devices that plug into my front or back AUX port. My monitor is set up with Displayport, and I can play music through that with no issue.

I have installed and reinstalled my audio drivers with no change to the issue. I have gone through auto troubleshooting and disabling, re-enabling the drive in the dev manager, and still nothing.

The error even continued through when I updated the OS from Windows 10 to 11. My OS was deactivated after going to windows 11, for some reason, but I doubt it's related.

At this point, I think it's an issue with the audio chip on my mobo, but I dont understand why it doesn't affect YouTube or video games. Does anyone have any ideas?

Pc specs:

CPU: Ryzen 7 5700G

RAM: 4x 16 gig DDR4-3600 G-Skill Trident Z Nero

MOBO: ASRock B550 Steel Legend

M.2: RAID0 Samsung 980 1TB (2x 1 TB drives in RAID0)

GPU: Gigabyte Eagle OC GTX 4080 16 gig

Comment: I did. Ive installed and reinstalled them

Comment: Harrymc, read my post please before commenting